# How to count Letters inside a string?

Tags: javascript, string, letter

My Code:

```
function letterCounter(str) {
    var letters = 0;
    var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    for (var i=0; i<str.length;i++) {
        if (str[i] === alphabet.split("")) {
            letters = letters + str[i];
        }
    }
    console.log(letterCounter("Hello World!!!1"));
}
```

I am not sure what mistake I am making and I am getting 0 letters as my answer.
Thank you.

Comment: Have a closer look at `str[i] === alphabet.split("")`

Comment: You are also calling letterCounter from inside letterCounter. I think you want to move the console.log statement outside the last brace.

Comment: BTW, do you expect the letter count as the result?

Comment: What do you suggest I should instead of 
` str[i] === alphabet.split("") `

Comment: What should be the result of your example code? if you want result `15` you dont need this kind of function just `str.length`

Comment: I want my output to be 10.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are comparing a character to an array in your code with `str[i] === alphabet.split("")` which makes no sense, you need to check if the character is inside the array. Also, the `console.log` must not be inside the function, or it will make it be called recursively infinite number of times.

Use

```js
function letterCounter(str) {
    var letters = 0;
    var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    var ar = alphabet.split("");
    for (var i=0; i<str.length;i++) {
        if (ar.indexOf(str[i]) > -1) {
            letters = letters + 1;
        }
    }
    return letters;
}
console.log(letterCounter("Hello World!!!1"));
```

Another way is to use a regex:

```js
var s = "Hello World!!!1";
var rx = /[a-z]/gi;
var m = s.match(rx);
if (m) {
  console.log(m.length);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use regex for it:

```js
function letterCounter (x) {
  return x.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, '').length;
}

console.log(letterCounter('Hello World!!!1'))
```

Answer (score 1):

To calculate number count of the letter `e` for example:

```js
var str = "Hello hello hello hello";
var lengthOfE = str.match(/e/gi).length;
console.log(lengthOfE);
```

Then use this in loop to calculate each element's count